# Devise Omniauth-facebook No route matches [GET] "/users/auth/facebook/callback"

Tags: devise, routes, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4

I got a question will trying to use **omniauth-facebook** with **devise**
I followed this [railscast video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised)(just substitute twitter with facebook) and was able to get it work.
However, I would like to customize my routes a little bit, so this is what I did:

**config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, path: 'accounts', 
           controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks" },
           path_names: { sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout", sign_up: "signup" }
```

**app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Successfully signed in via #{request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider}!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :facebook, :all
end
```

as I expected, in my url "users/..." was changed to "accounts/...", but when I tried to login via facebook, I got this error:
`Routing Error`
`No route matches [GET] "/users/auth/facebook/callback"`

after play around with it, I got around it by adding this line:

**config/routes.rb**

```
get '/users/auth/facebook/callback', to: redirect('/accounts/auth/facebook/callback')
```

It works fine now, but I think there must be better solution.

Is there any way to change the returned callback url from `/users/auth/facebook/callback` to `/accounts/auth/facebook/callback`    ???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems Solved, I forgot to set window.location in Javascript code.
After I changed my window.location, it's working fine